# Use $CI_JOB_ID as a constant across multiple stages of Gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following

```
stages:
    - stage1
    - stage2
variables:
        MY_ENV_VAR: env_$CI_JOB_ID
stage1_build:
    stage: stage1
    script:
        - echo $MY_ENV_VAR
stage2_build:
    stage: stage2
    script:
        - echo $MY_ENV_VAR
```

I get different values for `$MY_ENV_VAR` in the two stages (which means `$CI_JOB_ID` changes on every stage).

What I want is set `$MY_ENV_VAR` once with one value of `$CI_JOB_ID` and make it a constant, so that the same value of `$MY_ENV_VAR` is used across all stages.

Comment: I think what you're describing is the same as `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` ? That will be constant for all jobs in the pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` instaed, which will be constant across all jobs in the pipeline.

```yaml
variables:
  MY_ENV_VAR: env_$CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

See [predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for additional reference.

If you really want an environment variable to be created in one job and persist for the rest of the pipeline, you can pass variables between jobs using `artifacts:reports:dotenv`.

```yaml
stages:
    - stage1
    - stage2

set_env:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    echo "MY_ENV_VAR=env_$CI_JOB_ID" > .myenv
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: .myenv

stage1_build:
    stage: stage1
    script:
        - echo $MY_ENV_VAR
stage2_build:
    stage: stage2
    script:
        - echo $MY_ENV_VAR
```

Comment: Off topic question. `stage1_build` and `stage2_build` are run by different runners (because admin has enabled shared runners for this project). Can I have have the two builds run in a single runner, but sequentially?

Comment: @ontherocks to use the _same_ runner, the runner would have to be uniquely tagged and you would need to use `tags:` matching one of the runner's unique tags. In general this should not be needed unless the runner has some special capability. Also keep in mind that, even when your jobs run on the same runner, each job generally gets its own fresh build environment; state does not necessarily persist between jobs even on the same runner. The use of ordered stages will ensure sequential order.